# Checking the solution for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was testing a certain solution for a differential equation and trying to determine whether it really is a solution or not; That's how it went:

$x=-y =>$

$(2\cdot - y -y)dx - (-y+y)dy = -3ydx = 0 $ . From here I have to infer whether  $x=-y$ is indeed a solution to the differential equation or not. Nonetheless, I don't know how to infer it from the last expression.

Eventually the question boils down to whether or not  $-3ydx = 0 $. Which is something I can't determine.

Comment: @Back1139 : Before checking the solution, check the initial equation  $(2\cdot - y -y)dx - (-y+y)dy = -3ydx = 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

The "= 0" is confusing. "$2\cdot -y- y$" would be more easily written "-3y" and $(-y+ y)$ is 0.  So apparently the equation is simply "-3y dx= 0".  If x= -y then y= -x so -3y= 3x.  No, -3y dx= 3xdx is NOT 0.  In fact the general solution to -3ydx= 0, which is the same as dx= 0, is that x is a constant.